# How to format date from the object in angular

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
data = { name: 'Jaun', date: '2019-01-01 13:29:00', load: true }
```

what I want to do here is to format the date when it console the data it should be like this.

```
 data = { name: 'Jaun', date: '01-01-2019 01:29 PM', load: true }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried creating a Date object from data.date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let data = {
  name: 'Jaun',
  date: '2019-01-01 13:29:00',
  load: true
};
const addZero = (num) => num < 10 ? `0${num}` : num;
const d = new Date(data.date);
let hr = addZero(d.getHours());
const min = addZero(d.getMinutes());
let ampm = 'AM';
if (Number(hr) > 12) {
  hr -= 12;
  ampm = 'PM';
}
const date = addZero(d.getDate());
const month = addZero(d.getMonth() + 1);
const year = d.getFullYear();
data.date = `${date}-${month}-${year} ${hr}:${min} ${ampm}`;

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```js
var data = { name: 'Jaun', date: '2019-01-01 13:29:00', load: true }

function convertDate(){
 console.log(moment(data.date).format('DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="convertDate()">Convert Date</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it easily using `toLocaleString` in `Date` class
it would be easy like this

```
data.date = new Date(data.date).toLocaleString().replace(/\//g, '-')
```

after that, you will need to replace `/` with `-`

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the locale string as an argument to DatePipe.

```
var ddMMyyyy = this.datePipe.transform(data.date,"dd-MM-yyyy");
```

also add datepipe in app.component.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {DatePipe} from '@angular/common';
@NgModule({
   declarations: [
   AppComponent
 ],
 imports: [
  BrowserModule
 ],
 providers: [
  DatePipe
 ],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Ref: [angular formatDate](https://angular.io/api/common/formatDate)